# Generate a list of indices by matching items in a master list in python

Tags: python

Newbie question: suppose I have some categories and data:

```
categories = ['cow', 'pig', 'rat', 'hen', 'dog', 'cat']
data = ['hen', 'cat', 'pig', 'hen', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'hen' ]
```

How can I generate a list of numerical labels for the data, where the label is the index of the data item in the master list of categories? That is, generate the list `[3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 4, 2, 3 ]`... which certainly does not result from this:

```
label = [index for item in data if categories[index] == item]    # useless!!
```

I am aware that this list can be generated by using the scikit-learn `LabelEncoder`. How can it be done in pure python?

Comment: ```[num for word in data for (num, w) in enumerate(categories) if word == w]``` just a play and unnecessary, as the other answers are suitable. just thought of seeing it through another approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will take care of the items that doesn't exist in the categories list.
It will give `-1` value to those elements.

```
categories = ['cow', 'pig', 'rat', 'hen', 'dog', 'cat']
data = ['hen', 'cat', 'pig', 'hen', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'hen' ]
print([categories.index(i) if i in categories else -1 for i in data])
```

Comment: Clear, compact and correct - I'm not able to judge which answer is the most "pythonic"... but this feels like it to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try list `index` function:-

```
categories = ['cow', 'pig', 'rat', 'hen', 'dog', 'cat']
data = ['hen', 'cat', 'pig', 'hen', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'hen' ]

res = []

for i in data:
    if i in categories:
        res.append(categories.index(i))
    else:
        res.append(-1)

print(res)
```

Output will be:-

```
[3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 4, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is premature optimization, but I would probably map the category names to the index first to avoid doing a double nested loop through all the categories:

```
categories = ['dog', 'fish', 'tree', 'toad']
data = ['toad', 'tree', 'dog', 'fish', 'toad', 'toad']

m = { name : idx for idx,name in enumerate(categories) }

print([ m[n] for n in data])
```

Comment: I would hope that there is never any stray data - 'owl', for example - but I can't see that there is an obvious extension to this method to cope with it. I have accepted a different answer on this basis.

Comment: I guess the way I would handle that would be to--after creating `m`--pull all the unknown labels out of `data` and append them to `m`. However, this means you'd end up with indices in your final array that were outside the bounds of `categories`, indices into an array (or just values in your map) created at runtime. If that doesn't work well, depending on your use case, maybe it might be better to just make sure up front that `categories` contains all the labels. Anyway those are my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  You need to use the list lookup function, `index`:

```
[categories.index(name) if name in categories else "missing" 
     for name in data]
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It would give same index for elements that does not exist and the element at `0th` index.

Comment: Yup ... OP left that undefined, but this isn't the best idea.  Updating ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def solve(categories, data):
    index_dict = dict(zip(categories, range(len(categories))))
    return [index_dict.get(i, "Not Found") for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categories = ['cow', 'pig', 'rat', 'hen', 'dog', 'cat']
data = ['hen', 'cat', 'pig', 'hen', 'dog', 'cow', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'hen' ]
for i in range(0,len(categories)):
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        if categories[i]==data[j]:
           data[j]=i
```

this might help